# Threshold for LDA in the case of three classes

Tags: classification, multi-class, threshold

The result of discriminant analysis for the three classes are two discriminant functions LD1 and LD2.

In the case of two classes, there is one discriminant function **LD1**, and the threshold of discrimination can be calculated as follows:
$$
C = \frac{1}{2}(M_{1} + M_{2})
$$
**M1** is the mean value of LD1 estimates for class 1, and **M2** for class 2.

Please, help me understand how, with **LD1** and **LD2**, calculated threshold of discrimination for the case of three classes.

UPD
[image]

How I can find the equations of these thresholds lines on a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The threshold can not be "calculated" by that formula. That formula is one (!) possibility for *setting* that threshold.

There is an enormous amount of misinformation regarding thresholds for classification. [I recommend reading this earlier thread.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352) It does not explicitly address your three-level classification case, but can be applied to it: the solution is to think about your costs of misclassification and set thresholds accordingly.

[Even better is to discard thresholds in the *statistical* analysis entirely and work with purely probabilistic predictions.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352)

Comment: Very grateful for your answer. It helped me a little to understand how I can use probabilistic prediction in my case.